# Do vs. did in "do you want to join us?"

Tags: tenses, politeness, do-support

What exactly is the difference in meaning between the questions

> Do you want to join us?

and

> Did you want to join us?

in the context of a group of people asking asking another person who happens to be in the same place (for example, friends having dinner in a restaurant and bumping into another friend).

I would use the first variant, because to me "did" implies that the person who is asked had made up his/her mind before the question was asked.

Comment: *"**Do** you want to join us?"* is often used when the speaker is making an offer, where that offer might be unexpected by the addressee. While, *"**Did** you want to join us?"* could be the speaker acknowledging that the addressee wants to join in with the group--it is not necessarily an offer by the speaker. For the situation that you are describing, perhaps better would be: *"Would you like to come and join us?"*, or *"Please, do come and join us?"*, etc.

Comment: @F.E.: I cannot imagine any real-life context where the intended audience would not realise whether an offer was in fact being made, so there would be no need to adopt "better" phrasing to avoid ambiguity.